# One-to-many relationship without actual foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-key-relationship

I want to make a one-to-many relationship like in the tutorial.

~~~
One To Many

An example of a one-to-many relation is a blog post that "has many" comments. We can model this relation like so:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

}
```

~~~

So i want to make a Model Post (connected to table "posts") and a Model Comment (connected to table 'comments').  I am creating the tables in phpMyAdmin and not with migrations (because i have no SSH support on the online server). The comments table has a column 'posts_id'.

Can i use  ...

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments;
```

..without defining a foreign key relationship between the two tables in phpmyadmin?

And if the answer is YES.

Should i make a column name "post_id"  or something like this in my 'comments' table or something for this to work? Just like you would do with a normal foreign key?

Comment: why do you want to avoid defining a foreign key relationship?  It may be tricky to set up, but it guarantees your table structure will be correct and stay correct.  It will prevent 'orphan' comments not referencing any post...and prevent problems on moving / deleting a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly declare a foreign key in the MySQL side but you have at least to create a `post_id` column that will be used by Laravel as a foreign key.

Of course, you can name this column as you want and specify it in the declaration of the relation :

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_primary_key');
    }

}
```

You can also declare this column as a foreign key in PHPMyAdmin to improve robustness of your database but that's not Laravel business.

Comment: hi! How would I manage to do something like: for each table row, I want an entire retrieve of a specific table. Something like: comments, flag_list, count_flags. Comment->flag_list = entire flag table with associated count_flag (for that commen) in each row